# Работа в Canvas с учетом декартовой системы координат

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas, координаты

Всем привет. Я получаю графические данные в декартовой системе координат:
[image: Исходные данные]

Мне нужно эту геометрию отобразить в Canvas в таком-же виде. При этом я не хочу применять трансформацию к самому Canvas (т.е. не делать типа ScaleTransform(1, -1)).
Мне нужно просто менять координаты при передаче на холст и потом конвертировать их обратно.
Никак не могу сообразить как это лучше реализовать

Comment: то есть вам нужно применить трансформацию к координатам вашей геометрии?

Comment: Либо трансформацией, либо конвертером

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну я имел ввиду математическую трансформацию, без разницы, как именно автор её реализует :)

Comment: @tym32167, ну я озвучил варианты, которые я знаю :)

Comment: Имеется ввиду не что применять (конвертеры, трансформации и пр), а то именно нужно трансформировать и как